# QBluetoothSocket: connecting to multiple services

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, qt5, uuid

On my linux system w/ bluez5 and Qt5.6.1 I'm trying to write a code to connect to several services on my smartphone.

I'm able to discover and pair the phone from my application.
Then I query for the availables services. As you know some services (like HSP or HFP) have more than one UUID.

First question: should I connect them one by one, after QBluetoothSocket has connected successfully to the previous?

Second question: if I want to connect to multiple services (i.e. A2DP + HFP) should I use the same QBluetoothSocket?

I'm going to create a QQueue where I will append the UUIDs I'm interested to.